# How to do calculation T = 2.01*sqrt(L) in C and inline assembly

Tags: assembly, gcc, x86, inline-assembly

I am stuck because I do not know how I would approach this problem. I am trying calculate T = 2.01 * sqrt(L) where L is an input from the user, and T is the answer. I am writing this in C using GCC with calculations done in inline assembly.

I have the following code so far:

```
int physics(double z)
{
    double ans = 0;
    double i = 2.01;

    asm
    (
        "movl %[z1], %%eax \n"
        "movl %[i1], %%ebx \n"

        :[ans] "=m" (ans)
        :[z1] "m" (z), [i1] "m" (i)

        :"eax", "ebx"
    )
    return ans;
}
```

Comment: `z` is a `double`, you don't want to load it into GP integer registers.  The instruction you want is `sqrtsd %[z1], %%xmm0`.  Then multiply it and movsd to %[ans], if you insist on producing a memory output instead of just telling the compiler the output is in an `"=x"` XMM register output ready for it to return.

Comment: Not sure if you are using SIMD instructions like SSE or your assignment is using x87. If it is x87 it could look like `asm ("fsqrt\n\t"`
         `"fmulp"`
         `: "=t" (ans)`
         `: "0" (z), "u" (i)`
         `: "st(1)");`

Comment: I just noticed the return value is supposed to be `int`.  It's still fine to produce the output in an xmm register, but instead of being returned directly the compiler would need to emit a `cvttsd2si %xmm0, %eax` or something.  Same difference as far as the asm is concerned; you're producing `double ans` as output.  But is multiplying by `2.01` just a crappy way to bump rounding error up?  e.g. if you expect a whole number as a result, and you want to avoid something like 5.9999 truncating to 5 instead of 6?  If so, you can convert to integer yourself with the default rounding mode (nearest).

Comment: please [remove the line numbers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252559/995714). It's completely useless here and prevents people from trying your code